# Derivation of Morpheme for "Raising" in NACLO Problem

Tags: morphology, verbs, morphemes, tense-aspect-mood, american-languages

**The Problem**

[image]
[image]

**The Solution**

[image]

**Partial Explanation**

*chak* appears in both (11) and (12), both of which are about catching. It doesn't appear anywhere else, so we can assume it is some form of "catching".

*wen* appears where the subject is plural and there is "used to".

*pem* appears where there is "they".

*in* appears often, but it seems uncorrelated to the appearance of "me" or "I". So by process of elimination, we can assume *ni* means "me".

So for (12), it follows a [*object*][*verb*][*subject*][*auxiliary verb*] form.

The English translation of L2 follows a pattern similar to (12). We see *chem* and "we" in (1) and  (10), and we have the *wen* established earlier.

**The Confusion**

I have two questions:

1. Why is the object in the solution *i*? *i* appears in (13), but (13) contains the plural form of "you". L2 is for the singular form of "you".
2. Why is the verb *wel* (which seemingly means "grow" from (5))? Sure, in English it is commonly said "I grew this plant", which is "I am raising this plant". But how do we know that that is how it is said in Cupeño? For example, in China, "ni chī le ma" is "Have you eaten?", which is a way of greeting someone. But in most other countries and languages, you wouldn't go to someone and say "Have you eaten?" as a way of greeting.

**The Thanks**

Thanks

Comment: For #2, I would guess they’re expecting you to extrapolate. _Puy_ appears in (9) meaning ‘dine’, but also in (10), where it’s in a transitive construction and is translated as ‘feed’. ‘Feed’ = ‘cause to eat’ and ‘raise’ = ‘cause to grow’, so they’re quite parallel.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet so like causatives?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant causative, not transitive! Have added a looooong answer that gives more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *not* an easy task, if that’s all the data and information about Cupeño you’re given. Some things you can work out, but others do not seem possible to extract from just those data. As far as I can tell, it is not possible to arrive unambiguously at the correct answer without further information – although not for the reasons you cite.

Let’s start from the beginning:

### Affixes

It should be fairly clear from the data that the Cupeño verb is highly compound, consisting of verbal roots and various pre- and suffixes. You’ve identified some of these affixes: *-wen* indicates the imperfect/habitual, *pem-* is the 3pl subject pronoun. Some more can be adduced:

##### Subject

> *pi**ne**hamanin*, ***ne**puyqal*, *imichakw**ne**n*
> *pulin**chem**yax*, *pi**chem**puynin*

Three examples have a 1sg subject; all contain *ne-*, which means ‘I’. Two examples have 1pl subject and contain *chem-* ‘we’.

> ***e**wel*, *chakw**e**yax*
> ***em**pulinwen*, *piwix**em**inwen*

Two examples have 2sg subject and contain *e-* ‘thou’. Two have 2pl subject, *em-* ‘ye’.

> *chimichung**pe**nqal*
> *wix**pem**yax*, ***pem**hamawen*, *nichakw**pem**inwen*

One example has 3sg subject, *pe-* ‘he/she/it’. Three have 3pl subject, *pem-* ‘they’.

It’s not really clear from *chimichungpenqal* that the subject affix is *pe-*, but if you look at the system, it seems most likely: singular/plural pairs are *ne-/chem-*, *e-/em-*, *X/pem-*, so *-m-* appears to be the plural marker, and *pe-* is the obvious candidate for X.

##### Object

> ***ni**chakwpeminwen*
> ***chimi**chungpenqal*

One example with 1sg object, *ni-* ‘me’. One with 1pl object, *chimi-* ‘us’.

> ***imi**chakwnen*

No examples with 2sg object ‘thee’. One with 2pl object, *imi-* ‘you’.

> ***pi**nehamanin*, ***pi**wixeminwen*, ***pi**chempuynin*

Three examples with 3sg object, *pi-* ‘him/her/it’. None with 3pl object ‘them’.

If we compare the subject system above, it looks like the vowel *e* is substituted with *i* in the object affixes:

| Person | Singular (subj ~ obj) | Plural (subj ~ obj) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ne ~ ni | chem ~ chim(i) |
| 2 | e ~ ?? | em ~ im(i) |
| 3 | pe ~ pi | pem ~ ?? |

Presumably, then, the object forms of 2sg and 3pl are *i-* and *pimi-*, respectively.<sup>1</sup>

(From the data here, there’s no way to tell whether the final *i* in *chimi-* and *imi-* [and *pimi-*] are part of the object prefix, or if they’re some other prefix that just happen to appear after *chim-* and *im-*; but you also don’t need to know that in order to solve the task.)

##### TAM(ish) markers

Three markers are easily discernible in the examples that indicate various aspects of the verb’s meaning: *-qal* (sg.) / *-wen* (pl.) marks the imperfect/habitual past, *-yax* appears to form passives, and *-nin-* appears to form causatives.

Less obvious is *-in-*, which only appears in transitive clauses, so let’s assume it marks transitivity (the answer key implicitly confirms that it does).

That takes care almost everything that’s not a verbal root. The only elements that are not yet clear are *-pen-* and *-nen-* in *chimichung**pen**qal* ‘he used to kiss us’ and *imichakw**nen*** ‘I caught you’. Given that both these sentences have object prefixes, and neither has the causative suffix *-nin-*, they ought to be simple transitive sentences and contain the suffix *-in-*. Given that *pe-* and *ne-* are the subject pronouns in 1sg and 3sg (both of which match the subjects in the translations), we can safely assume that **ne-in-* > *-nen-* and *-pe-in-* > *-pen-*. Similarly *e-in-* presumably becomes *en-*.

### Order of constituents

Probably the most difficult thing about this task is the order of the different parts of the verbal cluster, because it does not appear to be fixed at first glance.

Let’s start with the easiest parts:

##### Objects

> ***pi**nehamanin*, ***chimi**chungpenqal*, ***pi**wixeminwen*, ***pi**chempuynin*, ***ni**chakwpeminwen*, ***imi**chakwnen*

Every single object pronoun in the examples comes at the very beginning, whether the verb is transitive or causative. Let’s assume that’s always the case. Slot 1 = object pronoun.

##### TAM(ish) markers

> *empulin**wen***, *chimichungpen**qal***, *pemhama**wen***, *piwixemin**wen***, *nepuy**qal***, *nichakwpemin**wen***
> *pulinchem**yax***, *wixpem**yax***, *chakwe**yax***
> *pinehama**nin***, *pichempuy**nin***

The imperfect/habitual past marker *-qal/-wen*, the passive marker *-yax* and the causative marker *-nin* always come at the very end, but don’t co-occur in any of the examples, so their internal order is undetermined and we have no choice but to put them in the same slot. Slot X-1 = imperfect/passive/causative.

> *chimichungpe**n**qal*, *piwixem**in**wen*, *nichakwpem**in**wen*, *imichakwne**n***

The transitive suffix *-(i)n-* appears right before the imperfect/passive/causative suffixes. Slot X-2 = transitive.

##### Subjects

This is where it gets tricky, because it’s clear that subjects appear both before and after the verbal root (giving the root in caps here to illustrate):

Before:

> *pi**ne**HAMAnin*, ***em**PULINwen*, ***e**WEL*, ***pem**HAMAwen*, ***ne**PUYqal*, *pi**chem**PUYnin*

After:

> *pulin**chem**yax*, *chimiCHUNG**pe**nqal*, *WIX**pem**yax*, *piWIX**em**inwen*, *CHAKW**e**yax*, *niCHAKW**pem**inwen*, *imiCHAKW**ne**n*

So what is the logic?

Let’s look at the TAM(ish) markers and see how they are distributed in the two groups:

| Marker | Before | After |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ø (none) | X |  |
| -nin | X |  |
| -yax |  | X |
| -in |  | X |
| -qal/-wen | X | X |

We can see that *-qal/-wen* appears in both groups, so that doesn’t seem to make a difference to subject position.

But *-nin* only appears in the ‘before’ group, and the same is true of forms with no marker at all; conversely, *-yax* and *-in* only appear in the ‘after’ group.

So let’s assume that there are two subject slots: one before the root and one after; and that the latter is used in passive and transitive constructions, while the former is used elsewhere.

### Constituent overview<sup>2</sup>

| Object | Subject I | ROOT | Subject II | Transitive | Impf./pass./caus. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

### Creating the solution

There is no verb ‘raise’ in any of the examples, so we have to get creative. We can see from examples (9) and (10) that *puy* means ‘eat, dine’ when intransitive, but ‘feed’ when causative.

Since raising someone is essentially ‘causing them to grow’, we can make the reasonable assumption that *wel*, which means ‘grow [up]’ when intransitive, would mean ‘raise’ when causative, so we can use *wel* and make a causative construction.

Alternatively, we can assume that ‘grow’ can be both intransitive and transitive in Cupeño, just as in English: the wheat *grows*; the farmer *grows* the wheat. So perhaps we can use a transitive construction instead of a causative one.

The trouble with the causative construction is that, as we saw above, the imperfective marker required for ‘used to’ is in the same slot as the causative marker – none of the examples have both, so we don’t know how they would appear if both are present, which they have to be here. We’ll just have to guess. ‍♂️

The trouble with not actually having ‘raise’ in any of the examples is that we have no way of knowing for sure whether the causative or the transitive option is correct – or indeed, if they both are (as the provided answer implies they are).

##### Causative construction

This is how we’d make up the form required for the causative construction:

- [slot 1] the object always comes first, and the 2sg object form is *i-*
- [slot 2] causative constructions appear in the ‘before’ group, so the subject goes in the first subject slot; the 1pl subject form is *chem-*
- [slot 3] the verb is *wel*
- [slot 4] the second subject slot is not used in causative constructions
- [slot 5] as far as we can tell, the transitive marker does not co-occur with the causative marker, so this is empty as well
- [slot 6] causative marker *-nin* **and** imperfective plural marker *-wen*

| i | chem | WEL | - | - | nin ~ wen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

The best answer we can come up with is either **ichemwelninwen** or **ichemwelwennin**. From the answer provided, it’s clear the first of these is the correct one, but the data is not sufficient to arrive at this conclusion.

##### Transitive construction

This is how we’d make up the form required for the transitive construction:

- [slot 1] the object always comes first, and the 2sg object form is *i-*
- [slot 2] the first subject slot is not used in transitive constructions
- [slot 3] the verb is *wel*
- [slot 4] transitive constructions appear in the ‘after’ group, so the subject goes in the second subject slot; the 1pl subject form is *chem-*
- [slot 5] transitive marker *-in*
- [slot 6] imperfective plural marker *-wen*

| i | - | WEL | chem | in | wen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

For this construction, the answer is unambiguous and can only be **iwelcheminwen**.

---

##### Notes

<sup><sup>1</sup> In actual fact, the 3pl object form is just *mi-*, but there is absolutely no way to know that from the data provided.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> If you look at actual grammatical descriptions of Cupeño, you’ll find that there are more than six slots; eight is the most common number given. The order of the elements found in this exercise is really [obj] [subj I] [ROOT] [subj II] [-in-, -yax-] [-nin-] [-qal/-wen].</sup>