# 'London in' or 'in London'? 'ed-learn' or 'learned'?

Tags: prepositions, morphemes, function

In English, ‘in London’ and 'learned’ are grammatically correct. Grammatical elements or forms are divided into two categories: grammatical or functional words like prepositions or auxiliary verbs in English, and grammatical or functional morphemes like affixes attached to nouns and verbs. They are represented here as G and the headwords as H.

The first question is “Is there any language that accepts both GH and HG as grammatical?” My supposition is that there are some languages of this kind in the world.

My second question is a little trickier to answer. “Is there any language that accepts both GH and HG as grammatical and in which G has a different grammatical function either in GH or in HG?” My hypothesis is that there is no language of this type in the world, but adverbials which are very like grammatical elements might be positioned before and after the headwords and have different grammatical meanings.

Comment: are you interested only in languages where both GH and HG are acceptable for all G & for all H, or are those where both GH and HG are acceptable for certain morphosyntactic classes of G & H also relevant?

Comment: for the latter, most early Indo-European languages seem to have been pretty flexible on placing adjectives before or after nouns (although obviously there were tendencies), so they allow both GH & HG when H is a noun and G is an adjective

Comment: The two examples you give are very dissimilar. There are definitely cases of languages where prepositions can come either before or after their object (or be entirely separated from it), such as Latin and Ancient Greek; but I don’t know of any language where inflectional morphemes are treated this way. In all languages I’m familiar with, those invariably appear in a specific slot. Some languages may have slots for the same morpheme both before and after the root (e.g., [Cupeño](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/45807/2253)), but their distribution still follows specific rules.

Comment: I assume that languages with declension or with agglutinative morphology which put  a morpheme or a particle at the end to mean "in" don't count as "London in". However, if they count, you could find a lot of languages. For example, in basque "in London" is "Londresen" (from Londres+en).

Comment: @Pere But it’s **always** _Londresen_, which is HG; there is no GH variant like _enLondres_ in Basque. The question as I understand it is asking for examples of languages where you can put inflections (and other potentially inflection-like grammatical elements) either before or after their heads with no difference.

Comment: I am asking for examples of languages where you can put inflections (and other potentially inflection-like grammatical elements) either before or after their heads with no difference. What is more important for me, I am asking for examples of languages where you can put inflections either before or after their heads with grammatical difference.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'd think the ability to place a marker either before or after (or even separated from) the head would be sufficient to argue something's a particle not an inflectional morpheme

Comment: @samhana Would you count cases like Cupeño mentioned above, where there are slots for things like subject and object markers both before and after the root in a verb form, but they’re in complementary distribution (i.e., in some constructions you use the pre-root slots, in others you use the post-root slots, but you can never use the opposite one in any given construction)?

Comment: Thank you very much for your instructive comment. I've read the intriguing article by Cupeño, but I have not imagined at all that subject and object markers both before and after the root in a verb form are in complementary distribution.

Comment: I am not sure whether your question is limited to bound morphemes or whether you are including other function words.  If the latter, in various types of Ancient Greek a "preposition" like ἀπο could be bound at the beginning of a verb governing an object, before the object, or after the object.  In Latin, demonstrative adjectives could precede, follow, or be discontinuous with their referents for different pragmatic effects.  Also, how about "take out" and "out take" or "overcome" and "come over"?